# SQL Subquery Issue

Tags: sql, subquery

I am trying to create a subquery(not a join) where I will list two columns from one table with a restriction in another table.

I am trying to list the CustomerName and CustomerPhone from the Customer Table for all Invoices greater than $50 from the Invoice table.

```
    SELECT CustomerName CustomerPhone
    FROM CUSTOMER, INVOICE
    WHERE TotalAmount IN
    (SELECT TotalAmount
    FROM INVOICE
    WHERE TotalAmount > 50);
```

How can I fix the subquery? It is showing all customer names.

Comment: You aren't restricting the join of Customer to Invoice, so you are linking every customer to every invoice.

Comment: Does `Invoice` table contain any `Primarykey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the extraneous cartesian product from the `from` clause and use appropriate columns for the `IN`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName c.CustomerPhone
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE c.CustomerId IN (SELECT i.CustomerId
                       FROM INVOICE i
                       WHERE i.TotalAmount > 50
                      );
```

You don't give guidelines on what the proper column names are, so I'm guessing.

Some advice:

- Do not use commas in the `from` clause.  Always use explicit `join` syntax.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of table names.
- Quality all column references so you know where they come from

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    CustomerName,
    CustomerPhone
FROM CUSTOMER c 
INNER JOIN INVOICE i ON
    c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId AND
    i.TotalAmount > 50
GROUP BY
    CustomerName,
    CustomerPhone
```